# Templated conversion operator in a template class with default constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, constructor

I want a templated class with a templated conversion operator and a default constructor, but my initial attempt isn't working.

```
template<typename T>
class C
{
public:
    C() {}

    template<typename U>
    operator U() 
    {
        C<U> c; // (*)
        c._a = dynamic_cast<U*>(_a); 
        return c;
    }
private:
    T* _a;
};
```

But now, when I try to create an instance of C,

```
template<typename T>
void F()
{
    ...
    C<T> obj;
}
```

operator U() keeps calling itself over and over at (*), eventually segfaulting.  The same thing happens when I define the function that does the casting externally and call it from operator U()--in which case there is no call to C::C() from within the class definition.

It seems to me then that the conversion operator is getting called when I want the default constructor called--it is essentially trying to convert itself.  But surely, there's a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in `operator X` (where `X` is a type) functions, you should usually return something of type `X`. You're returning a `C<U>` when you're trying to convert the invoking object to a `U` which causes the following to happen:

1. `int a = someC;` (where `someC` is a `C` of any type) will try to assign a `C<X>` to an `int`
2. `operator T<int>` will be called on `someC` which will return a `C<int>` and then try to assign it to an `int`
3. `operator T<int>` will be called on the aforementioned return value which will return a `C<int>`
4. That return value which is a `C<int>` will attempt to be converted to an `int` which will call `operator T<int>`....
5. `goto 3;`

Hopefully you can see why the infinite recursion and subsequent stack overflow occurs.

You cannot return a `C<U>` from `operator T<U>` of class `C`. You need to redesign your class if you need to for some reason.

Comment: Ha, great!  Sounds like you nailed it.  I want, in fact, to convert a C<T> to a C<U>.  So I guess I should try `operator C<U>`?  I'm away from the computer I did this on so I'll check this out tomorrow.  I think the fact that this is such a low-level mistake but the code still compiled is what threw me, but anyway, thanks, this sounds very promising.

Comment: @MattPhillips try `template<typename X> operator C<X>() { ... }` (actually yeah, exactly what you said)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I was using assembly, the natural choice for ordered lists :)

Comment: @MattPhillips:  It might be easier if you want to convert from C<T> to C<U> to use a templated constructor.

Comment: @Dave S A excerpt from the C++03 standard I found states explicitly that these can't happen.  Does C++11 now allow them?  A quick google didn't turn up anything for me.

Comment: @Matt:  I'm curious what exerpt that is. Check out boost::shared_ptr, it uses a templated constructor to convert from shared_ptr<U> to shared_ptr<T>.  Another (much simpler) example can be found here http://ideone.com/VZjHe